# Texture will not apply to my 3d Cube directX

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, directx

I am trying to apply a texture onto my 3d cube but it is not showing up correctly. I believe that it might some what be working because the cube is all brown which is almost the same complexion as the texture. And I did not originally make the cube brown. These are the steps I've done to add the texture

I first declared 2 new varibles

```
ID3D10EffectShaderResourceVariable* pTextureSR;
ID3D10ShaderResourceView* textureSRV;
```

I also added a variable and a struct to my shader .fx file

```
Texture2D tex2D;

SamplerState linearSampler
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};
```

I then grabbed the image from my local hard drive from within the .cpp file. I believe this was successful, I checked all varibles for errors, everything has a memory address. Plus I pulled resources before and never had a problem.

```
D3DX10CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(mpD3DDevice,L"crate.jpg",NULL,NULL,&textureSRV,NULL);
```

I grabbed the tex2d varible from my fx file and placed into my resource varible

```
pTextureSR = modelObject.pEffect->GetVariableByName("tex2D")->AsShaderResource();
```

And added the resource to the varible

```
pTextureSR->SetResource(textureSRV);
```

I also added the extra property to my vertex layout

```
D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] = {
    {"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0 , 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"COLOR",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0 , 12, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"NORMAL",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0 , 24, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"TEXCOORD",0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0 , 36, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
};
```

as well as my struct

```
struct VertexPos
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 pos;
    D3DXVECTOR4 color;
    D3DXVECTOR3 normal;
    D3DXVECTOR2 texCoord;
};
```

Then I created a new pixel shader that adds the texture to it. Below is the code in its entirety

```
matrix Projection;
matrix WorldMatrix;
Texture2D tex2D;

float3 lightSource;
float4 lightColor = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5};

// PS_INPUT - input variables to the pixel shader
// This struct is created and fill in by the 
// vertex shader
struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
    float4 Normal : NORMAL;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD;
};

SamplerState linearSampler
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};


////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Vertex Shader - Main Function
///////////////////////////////////////////////
PS_INPUT VS(float4 Pos : POSITION, float4 Color : COLOR, float4 Normal : NORMAL, float2 Tex : TEXCOORD)
{
    PS_INPUT psInput;

    // Pass through both the position and the color
    psInput.Pos = mul( Pos, Projection );
    psInput.Normal = Normal;
    psInput.Tex = Tex;

    return psInput;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Pixel Shader
///////////////////////////////////////////////
float4 PS(PS_INPUT psInput) : SV_Target
{
    float4 finalColor = 0; 
    finalColor = saturate(dot(lightSource, psInput.Normal) * lightColor);

    return finalColor;
}

float4 textured( PS_INPUT psInput ) : SV_Target
{
    return tex2D.Sample( linearSampler, psInput.Tex );
}



// Define the technique
technique10 Render
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetVertexShader( CompileShader( vs_4_0, VS() ) );
        SetGeometryShader( NULL );
        SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, textured() ) );
    }
}
```

Below is my CPU code. It maybe a little sloppy. But I am just adding code anywhere cause I am just experimenting and playing around. You should find most of the texture code at the bottom createObject

```
#include "MyGame.h"
#include "OneColorCube.h"
/* This code sets a projection and shows a turning cube. What has been added is the project, rotation and
a rasterizer to change the rasterization of the cube. The issue that was going on was something with the effect file
which was causing the vertices not to be rendered correctly.*/
typedef struct 
{
    ID3D10Effect* pEffect;
    ID3D10EffectTechnique* pTechnique;

    //vertex information
    ID3D10Buffer* pVertexBuffer;
    ID3D10Buffer* pIndicesBuffer;
    ID3D10InputLayout* pVertexLayout;

    UINT numVertices;
    UINT numIndices;
}ModelObject;

ModelObject modelObject;
// World Matrix
D3DXMATRIX                  WorldMatrix;
// View Matrix
D3DXMATRIX                  ViewMatrix;
// Projection Matrix
D3DXMATRIX                  ProjectionMatrix;
ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable* pProjectionMatrixVariable = NULL;
ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable* pWorldMatrixVarible = NULL;
ID3D10EffectVectorVariable* pLightVarible = NULL;
ID3D10EffectShaderResourceVariable* pTextureSR;


bool MyGame::InitDirect3D()
{
    if(!DX3dApp::InitDirect3D())
    {
        return false;
    }

    D3D10_RASTERIZER_DESC rastDesc;
    rastDesc.FillMode = D3D10_FILL_WIREFRAME;
    rastDesc.CullMode = D3D10_CULL_FRONT;
    rastDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
    rastDesc.DepthBias = false;
    rastDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0;
    rastDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0;
    rastDesc.DepthClipEnable = false;
    rastDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
    rastDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
    rastDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;

    ID3D10RasterizerState *g_pRasterizerState;
    mpD3DDevice->CreateRasterizerState(&rastDesc, &g_pRasterizerState);
    //mpD3DDevice->RSSetState(g_pRasterizerState);

    // Set up the World Matrix
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&WorldMatrix);
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&ViewMatrix, new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 10.0f, -20.0f), new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    // Set up the projection matrix
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&ProjectionMatrix, (float)D3DX_PI * 0.5f, (float)mWidth/(float)mHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);


    if(!CreateObject())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

//These are actions that take place after the clearing of the buffer and before the present
void MyGame::GameDraw()
{

    static float rotationAngleY = 15.0f;
    static float rotationAngleX = 0.0f;

    static D3DXMATRIX rotationXMatrix;
    static D3DXMATRIX rotationYMatrix;

    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&rotationXMatrix);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&rotationYMatrix);

    // create the rotation matrix using the rotation angle
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rotationYMatrix, rotationAngleY);
    D3DXMatrixRotationX(&rotationXMatrix, rotationAngleX);


    rotationAngleY += (float)D3DX_PI * 0.0008f;
    rotationAngleX += (float)D3DX_PI * 0.0005f;

    WorldMatrix = rotationYMatrix * rotationXMatrix;

    // Set the input layout
    mpD3DDevice->IASetInputLayout(modelObject.pVertexLayout);
    pWorldMatrixVarible->SetMatrix((float*)&WorldMatrix);

    // Set vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof(VertexPos);
    UINT offset = 0;
    mpD3DDevice->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &modelObject.pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // Set primitive topology
    mpD3DDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    //ViewMatrix._43 += 0.005f;

    // Combine and send the final matrix to the shader
    D3DXMATRIX finalMatrix = (WorldMatrix * ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix);
    pProjectionMatrixVariable->SetMatrix((float*)&finalMatrix);


    // make sure modelObject is valid


    // Render a model object
    D3D10_TECHNIQUE_DESC techniqueDescription;
    modelObject.pTechnique->GetDesc(&techniqueDescription);

    // Loop through the technique passes
    for(UINT p=0; p < techniqueDescription.Passes; ++p)
    {
        modelObject.pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0);

        // draw the cube using all 36 vertices and 12 triangles
        mpD3DDevice->Draw(36,0);
    }
}

//Render actually incapsulates Gamedraw, so you can call data before you actually clear the buffer or after you 
//present data
void MyGame::Render()
{
    DX3dApp::Render();
}

bool MyGame::CreateObject()
{

    //Create Layout
    D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] = {
        {"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0 , 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"COLOR",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0 , 12, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"NORMAL",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0 , 24, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"TEXCOORD",0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0 , 36, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };

    UINT numElements = (sizeof(layout)/sizeof(layout[0]));
    modelObject.numVertices = sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(VertexPos);

    for(int i = 0; i < modelObject.numVertices; i += 3)
    {
        D3DXVECTOR3 out;

        D3DXVECTOR3 v1 = vertices[0 + i].pos;
        D3DXVECTOR3 v2 = vertices[1 + i].pos;
        D3DXVECTOR3 v3 = vertices[2 + i].pos;

        D3DXVECTOR3 u = v2 - v1;
        D3DXVECTOR3 v = v3 - v1;

        D3DXVec3Cross(&out, &u, &v);
        D3DXVec3Normalize(&out, &out);

        vertices[0 + i].normal = out;
        vertices[1 + i].normal = out;
        vertices[2 + i].normal = out;
    }

    //Create buffer desc
    D3D10_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexPos) * modelObject.numVertices;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
    initData.pSysMem = vertices;
    //Create the buffer

    HRESULT hr = mpD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &initData, &modelObject.pVertexBuffer);
    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    /*
    //Create indices
    DWORD indices[] =
    {
        0,1,3,
        1,2,3
    };

    ModelObject.numIndices = sizeof(indices)/sizeof(DWORD);

    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * ModelObject.numIndices;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;

    initData.pSysMem = indices;

    hr = mpD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &initData, &ModelObject.pIndicesBuffer);
    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;*/


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Set up fx files
    LPCWSTR effectFilename = L"effect.fx";
    modelObject.pEffect = NULL;

     hr = D3DX10CreateEffectFromFile(effectFilename,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        "fx_4_0",
        D3D10_SHADER_ENABLE_STRICTNESS,
        0,
        mpD3DDevice,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &modelObject.pEffect,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    pProjectionMatrixVariable = modelObject.pEffect->GetVariableByName("Projection")->AsMatrix();
    pWorldMatrixVarible = modelObject.pEffect->GetVariableByName("WorldMatrix")->AsMatrix();
    pTextureSR = modelObject.pEffect->GetVariableByName("tex2D")->AsShaderResource();

    ID3D10ShaderResourceView* textureSRV;
    D3DX10CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(mpD3DDevice,L"crate.jpg",NULL,NULL,&textureSRV,NULL);

    pLightVarible = modelObject.pEffect->GetVariableByName("lightSource")->AsVector();
    //Dont sweat the technique. Get it!
    LPCSTR effectTechniqueName = "Render";

    D3DXVECTOR3 vLight(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    pLightVarible->SetFloatVector(vLight);

    modelObject.pTechnique = modelObject.pEffect->GetTechniqueByName(effectTechniqueName);
    if(modelObject.pTechnique == NULL)
        return false;

    pTextureSR->SetResource(textureSRV);


    //Create Vertex layout
    D3D10_PASS_DESC passDesc;
    modelObject.pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);

    hr = mpD3DDevice->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements,
        passDesc.pIAInputSignature,
        passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize,
        &modelObject.pVertexLayout);
    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

And here is my cube coordinates. I actually only added coordinates to one side. And that is the front side. To double check I flipped the cube in all directions just to make sure i didnt accidentally place the text on the incorrect side

```
//Create vectors and put in vertices

    // Create vertex buffer
    VertexPos vertices[] =
    {
        // BACK SIDES
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f,  5.0f, 5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f, 5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(1.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f,  5.0f, 5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),  D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,1.0)},

        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f,  5.0f, 5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f, 5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f,  -5.0f, 5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},

        // 2 FRONT SIDE
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f),  D3DXVECTOR2(2.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,2.0)},

        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,2.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f) , D3DXVECTOR2(2.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f,  -5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(2.0,2.0)},

        // 3
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, 5.0f,  5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f, 5.0f,  5.0f),  D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, 5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},

        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, 5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f, 5.0f, -5.0f),  D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},

        // 4
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f),  D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},

        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f),  D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f),  D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},

        // 5
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.5f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.5f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.5f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},

        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.5f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.5f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        { D3DXVECTOR3(5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f,1.0f,0.5f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},

        // 6
        {D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.5f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        {D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.5f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        {D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.5f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},

        {D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.5f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        {D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.5f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
        {D3DXVECTOR3(-5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f), D3DXVECTOR4(0.5f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f), D3DXVECTOR2(0.0,0.0)},
    };
```

Ok, so I added a HRESULT in the following code

```
HRESULT *pHResult = NULL;

D3DX10CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(mpD3DDevice,L"crate.jpg",NULL,NULL,&textureSRV,pHResult);
```

I checked the result and it returned nothing. the address for pHResult 0x00000 failure to evaluate expression. Not sure if its because its not loading crate.jpg correctly or what. The location is correct. I have crate.jpg in the same location as my effect.fx file. and I loaded my effect file the same way. "effect.fx"

If someone could look at my vertices and make sure my UV coords is correct. that would be great. I am a little skeptical about it.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I read in MSDN, that pHResult value usually returns NULL. So I added it like so...

pHResult = D3DX10CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(mpD3DDevice,L"crate.bmp",NULL,NULL,&textureSRV,NULL);
It returned as S_OK. I am clueless towards this issue.

Comment: That's quite a lengthy question ... well ... more likely a train of thought ending on an abandoned line.  

Whittle it down next time to get some interest.

Answer (score 2):

well I figured it out. In my vertex layout description, my offset's is off. I incremented my color by 12 when it should be 16 because rgba. Anyways, I corrected it and now the texture appears but incorrectly. I will post another for that issue.